# Efficient way to find longest streak of characters in string

Tags: java, algorithm

This code works fine but I'm looking for a way to optimize it. If you look at the long string, you can see 'l' appears five times consecutively. No other character appears this many times consecutively. So, the output is 5. Now, the problem is this method checks each and every character and even after the max is found, it continues to check the remaining characters. Is there a more efficient way?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(longestStreak("KDDiiigllllldddfnnlleeezzeddd"));
    }
    private static int longestStreak(String str) {
        int max = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            int count = 0;
            for (int j = i; j < str.length(); j++) {
                if (str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(j)) {
                    count++;
                } else break;
            }
            if (count > max) max = count;
        }
        return max;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this might fit better over on [https://codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Well, you could stop as soon as your current max exceeds the number of remaining characters (`max > str.length()-i`).

Comment: @Arnaud still not the optimal solution. See my answer below to get optimal solution in O(N) complexity.

Answer (score 2):

We could add variable for previous char count in single iteration. Also as an additional optimisation we stop iteration if `i + max - currentLenght < str.length()`. It means that max can not be changed:

```
private static int longestStreak(String str) {
    int maxLenght = 0;
    int currentLenght = 1;
    char prev = str.charAt(0);
    for (int index = 1; index < str.length() && isMaxCanBeChanged(str, maxLenght, currentLenght, index); index++) {
        char currentChar = str.charAt(index);
        if (currentChar == prev) {
            currentLenght++;
        } else {
            maxLenght = Math.max(maxLenght, currentLenght);
            currentLenght = 1;
        }
        prev = currentChar;
    }
    return Math.max(maxLenght, currentLenght);
}

private static boolean isMaxCanBeChanged(String str, int max, int currentLenght, int index) {
    return index + max - currentLenght < str.length();
}
```

Comment: How can I calculate its efficiency against any other method? @i.bondarenko

Comment: In terms of time complexity it is linear O(n). It is probably equals to some others. But as we can see I added an optimization and in some cases it is more efficient. For example if you have large string with very long streak in this case you stop the iteration earlier then the others algorithms (see condition in isMaxCanBeChanged(...)).

Comment: Any other quantitative way to measure its efficiency. like which return a no that it took x ms to do that @i.bondarenko

Comment: How many milliseconds the algorithm spends is very dependent on the computer configuration. We could run some tests on the same computer and compare different algorithms but I do not have such tests and it is really depends on test dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. C++ code:

```
string str = "KDDiiigllllldddfnnlleeezzeddd";
int longest_streak = 1, current_streak = 1; char longest_letter = str[0];
for (int i = 1; i < str.size(); ++i) {
    if (str[i] == str[i - 1])
        current_streak++;
    else current_streak = 1;
    if (current_streak > longest_streak) {
        longest_streak = current_streak;
        longest_letter = str[i];
    }
}
cout << "The longest streak is: " << longest_streak << " and the character is: " << longest_letter << "\n";
```

LE: If needed, I can provide the Java code for it, but I think you get the idea.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(longestStreak("KDDiiigllllldddfnnlleeezzeddd"));
    }
    private static int longestStreak(String str) {
        int longest_streak = 1, current_streak = 1; char longest_letter = str.charAt(0);
        for (int i = 1; i < str.length(); ++i) {
            if (str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(i - 1))
                current_streak++;
            else current_streak = 1;
            if (current_streak > longest_streak) {
                longest_streak = current_streak;
                longest_letter = str.charAt(i);
            }
        }
        return longest_streak;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you convert the code to Java cause I have no clue how C++ works.

Comment: @EsAMe The code he provided is very similar to Java.

Comment: It would be better if you do that, then it will be much easier for me to compare.

Comment: Done, check it now.

Comment: @EsAMe Please accept the answer that helped you. Accepting the answer not only makes the answer easier to find but also gives you reputation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a regex magic solution, which although a bit brute force perhaps gets some brownie points.  We can iterate starting with the number of characters in the original input, decreasing by one at a time, trying to do a regex replacement of continuous characters of that length.  If the replacement works, then we know we found the longest streak.

```
String input = "KDDiiigllllldddfnnlleeezzeddd";
for (int i=input.length(); i > 0; --i) {
    String replace = input.replaceAll(".*?(.)(\\1{" + (i-1) + "}).*", "$1");
    if (replace.length() != input.length()) {
        System.out.println("longest streak is: " + replace);
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
longest streak is: lllll
```

Answer (score 0):

The loop could be rewritten a bit smaller, but mainly the condition can be optimized:

```
i < str.length() - max
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Stream and collector. It should give all highest repeated elements.

**Code:**

```
String lineString = "KDDiiiiiiigllllldddfnnlleeezzeddd";
String[] lineSplit = lineString.split("");
Map<String, Integer> collect = Arrays.stream(lineSplit)
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.summingInt(e -> 1)));
int maxValueInMap = (Collections.max(collect.values()));
for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : collect.entrySet()) {
   if (entry.getValue() == maxValueInMap) {
      System.out.printf("Character: %s, Repetition: %d\n", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
   }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Character: i, Repetition: 7
Character: l, Repetition: 7
```

P.S I am not sure how efficient this code it. I just learned Streams.